# CakePHP 3.x route 301 redirects of old links to new links with language modification

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp

My question relates to creating general routes redirects in CakePHP 3.x.

I used to have the following structure of URLs in my website:

```
https://www...../controller/action?language=eng
https://www...../controller/action/slug?language=eng
https://www...../controller/action?language=pol
https://www...../controller/action/slug?language=pol
```

Currently I have the following structure of URLs:

```
https://www...../en/controller/action
https://www...../en/controller/action/slug                                                   
https://www...../pl/controller/action
https://www...../pl/controller/action/slug
```

How should I create $routes->redirect so that if a user enters an old link he or she is automatically redirected to the correct language page in new format? I have hundred of pages, I cannot create $routes->redirect individually for every page because it would be to much work.

Comment: read https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Comment: I prefer to use CakePHP redirect options (in routes.php)

Comment: Wrong approach, wasting resources unnecessarily. You prefer server->php->server->php, instead server->server->php

Comment: Could you please explain me on my example how should I better achive such redirect functionality which I need? I am open to your suggestion if it is better. I am a novice in this aspect.

Comment: Which server you use and which version ? example: Apache  2.4

Comment: The server is Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)

Comment: here is example how to use if / else https://serverfault.com/questions/920930/htaccess-rewriterule-if-else

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would try to englobe every prefix language into an array and therefore check through `$this->here` if there is `?language=` on the slugs.

Depending on which language, I check through `strpos` with PHP if the certain language forms part of the inserted URL.

If both conditions are false, I continue and jump to the next iteration of the loop.

Finally, if the conditions are met, I redirect it as I pointed out beforehands.
I hope that can give you a hint to a solution.

Cheers

```
 $lang = '?language=';
$slugArr = [$lang.'eng', $lang.'pol', $lang.'otherlang'];
foreach($slugArr as $slugName) {
    $pos = strpos($this->here, $slugName);
    $lang = strpos($this->here, 'eng') || strpos($this->here, 'pol');
    if($pos !== false && $lang !== false) {
        if($slugName === $lang.'eng') {
            Router::redirect('/controller/action?language=eng', '/en/controller/action/', array('status' => 301));
        } else if($slugName === $lanmg.'pol'){
            Router::redirect('/controller/action?language=pol', '/pol/controller/action/', array('status' => 301));
        }
    }else{
        continue;
    } 
}
```